# Python - I cant get names past the first one from a list

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i got a problem with my code.. so what I'm trying to do is to ask some random name and that program should tell you if a name is in the list

```
names = ["Demi", "Siru", "Datte", "Sony", "Jami", "Windy", "Paavo", "Roosa"]
x = input('Give a name: ')
for y in names:
    if(x==y):
        print( x + " is in a list" )
        break
    elif(y!=x):
        print("it's not in a list")
        break
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. [See here why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code would go through all the items in the list, and if one matches break out of it, but only if none of them matched, conclude that it is not found (so that part goes out of the loop), like this:

```
for y in names:
    if x == y:
        print("{} is in the list".format(x))
        break
else:
    print("it's not in the list")
```

Of course, it can be done without the loop completely:

```
if x in names:
    print("{} is in the list".format(x))
else:
    print("it's not in the list")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you check only the first item of the list and then break.

Try to remove the `break`.

Comment: this is what i got now:  
Give a name: Siru
it's not in a list
Siru is in a list
it's not in a list
it's not in a list
it's not in a list
it's not in a list
it's not in a list
it's not in a list

Comment: Yes. You see? It’s in the list :)

Comment: Now you can figure out how to rewrite the program so it doesn’t write “not in a list” million times. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through the list, making a comparison, then `break`ing out of the loop as soon as you've processed the first item. Remove `break`.

That aside, the solution to your problem is to use `if item in my_list:` instead of that `for` loop nonsense.

Alternatively, you could use `for: else:` like so:

```
for y in names:
    if x == y:
        print("yes it is in there")
        break
else:
    print("no it is not")
```

You'll see that `else:` is attached to the `for` loop itself, as opposed to the `if`. The `else` is checking to see whether there was no `break`. Break causes the loop to exit early.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['ed', 'edd', 'eddy']
  found = False
  end = False

  while(end != True):
      user_input = input('enter name... ')

      for name in names:
          if name == user_input:
              found = True

      if found:
          print('yep! the name {} is available'.format(name))
      else: 
          print('hold up! wait a minute! no name found!')        

  again = input('continue? [y/n] ? ')

  if again == 'n':
     end = True
  else:
     found = False
```

Comment: this one worked thank you but what i would also like to know is how to make it to tell if some name doesn't exist in a list?

Comment: @Meowmeow could you please check the code if it suites your requirements? :o

Comment: your code didn't really work, else it would be perfect, your else statement didn't run correctly, that's why i chose that other answer to be correct answer

Comment: @Meowmeow ah I see. I did fix the code above, and it should work now. I will leave code here for completness. Glad you found the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Use List Comprehension.

`x +"In List" if x in names else "Not in List"`